# Payment Shared 1.2.22 White Screen of Death

Tags: payment

CIVICRM is telling me that I need to update Payment Shared (aka "mjwshared").  But when I click on the button to upgrade it I get the White Screen of Death (WSOD).

RussIsForUS.com

WordPress 6.4.3
CiviCRM 5.70.1
Stripe Ext 6.10.2
Payment Shared 1.2.21 (trying to upgrade to 1.2.22)
Firewall 1.5.9

Comment: This is hard to answer without more detail. Are you able to get details from the log? See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/

Comment: Also which PHP version are you running?